# hg serve: How to make it available to be cloned?

Tags: windows, mercurial

I start hg serve from the command line without a problem using the command: "hg serve -p 9001 -v -a 127.0.0.1".

The server is initiated and reachable from my browser with the adress: http://localhost:9001/

When I open a second command line window, and type in hg clone http://127.0.0.1, it gives the output below.

```
real URL is http://localhost/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 42, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 27, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 64, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 127, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\ui.pyo", line 606, in warn
  File "mercurial\ui.pyo", line 453, in write_err
IOError: [Errno 12] Not enough space
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. But I don't know what. How can I make my repo ready to be cloned by others using hg clone?

edit: I had some progress. When I type hg clone http://127.0.0.1/ hg it copies the repo that is made available by hg serve.

But still I can't copy from another computer.

p.s. I'm using windows 7.

Comment: your clone command should end in :9001 since you need to provide port information too.  You must've been doing that since below it says you've got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave out the `-a 127.0.0.1`. Including it restricts `hg` to listening on the [loopback interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_network_interface) instead of an actual network interface.

Also, make sure your firewall allows connections from other machines to the port that `hg` is listening on.

Comment: thank you for your advice. but when I try to copy from another computer, entering hg clone http://127.0.0.1/ hg is not enough. I should somehow enter the ip number of the machine that I want to reach, right?

Comment: Yes, 127.0.0.1 always refers to the loopback adapter of the computer it's used on. You need either the host name or IP address of the computer running `hg serve`. On Windows, you can find this by typing `ipconfig` from the command line on the server.

Comment: thank you, I switched off the firewall by McAfee and everything seems to work now when I enter the ipadress of my host computer.